# Simple Templating for Config Files

Tags: administration

I need to manage a growing set of similar-but-different ASCII files.  ( It so happens that they're Apache VirtualHosts, but that's not particularly relevant. )  For each production website, the developers might want as many as four variant configs for a variety of reasons.

Would you please recommend your favorite templating system?  I know of a few, M4 and Template::Toolkit come to mind.   My most important feature isn't power, it's intuitive operation and elegant simplicity.

Comment: So I can't mention template toolkit?

Comment: Of course, if you think that's the best way to go.  I just want to make sure that I'm not missing something better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm a big fan of using `make` and `m4`. I set up Nagios configuration files with extensive use of `make` and `m4`; Nagios is full of repetitive blocks that can be simplified through the use of `m4`.

The nice thing about `make` and `m4` is that they are usually part of the base install or at least the base package repository on Linux and UNIX systems; with something like `Template::Toolkit` you'd have to install it. Perl is also heavier than `m4` and `make`.

You can also, if you like, set up a semi-automated `m4` run by putting this at the top of your `m4` file (assuming the file is `file.m4` for instance):

```
#!/usr/bin/m4 > file.conf
```

If you don't want to rewrite `file.conf`, then remove the redirection from the command:

```
#!/usr/bin/m4
```

You'd have to make the `file.m4` file executable then as well:

```
chmod +x file.m4
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd go for custom solution written in perl using e.g. Template::Toolkit. That way you can keep your code elegant and simple.